# Using URLRewriteFilter CSS and JS not loaded

Tags: javascript, css, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using URLRewriteFilter Clean a URL. I got it to work, but css and js files are not linked correctly.

Taken that my project is demo.

Here's my urlrewrite.xml file:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/([0-9]+)$</from>
    <to>/test.jsp?id=$1</to>
</rule>
```

so, when I go to http://localhost:8080/demo/1234

it will forward me to test.jsp and I can get the paramter id

but css style sheet and js script are not loading. All css and js files are in /css and /js folder in the project.

Here are the css and js script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css"/>
```

I added condition but not sure if it is correct.

condition:

```
<rule>
    <condition type="request-uri">^(?!.*\.?:jpg|png|css|js)$).*$</condition>
    <from>^/(.*).css$</from>
    <to>/css/$1.css</to>
</rule>
```

Could someone please let me know what I need to do. Some code example would help me greatly.

Thanks

Comment: Can someone help me out here??

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `URLRewriteFilter` forwards the url to your actual location so the problem is you path of url changes and the js, css and all other resources are searched on new path as per url.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css"/>
```

All you need to put context path here. If your css and js in named folder under respective project context path.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css"/>
```